# 特定のフォルダでcudaが読み込めなくなる

Tags: cuda, chainer

下記のようなコードを実行した時に特定のフォルダでエラーになってとても困った

```
import chainer
from chainer import cuda
cuda.get_device(0).use()
```

エラーではCUDAがセットアップされていないと言われるが、他のフォルダで実行できるのは確認できている

```
raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: CUDA environment is not correctly set up
(see https://github.com/pfnet/chainer#installation).module 'dis' has no attribute 'COMPILER_FLAG_NAMES'
```

Answer (score 1):

`dis.py` というファイルがローカルにあったことが原因だった。
`dis.py`は標準モジュールでchainerが依存しており、この名前のファイルがローカルにあると本来読み込みたいものが読み込めなくなる模様。